# Complexity of algorithms of function

Tags: algorithm, complexity-theory, binary-search

```
public Term[] allMatches(String prefix) {
    Term myword = new Term(prefix, 0);
    int firstindex = RangeBinarySearch.firstIndexOf(terms, myword, Term.byPrefixOrder(prefix.length()));
    int lastindex = RangeBinarySearch.lastIndexOf(terms, myword, Term.byPrefixOrder(prefix.length()));
    Term[] Matches = new Term[lastindex-firstindex+1];
    int j = 0;
    for (int i = firstindex; i <= lastindex; i++) {
        Matches[j] = terms[i];
        j++;
    }
    Arrays.sort(Matches,Term.byReverseWeightOrder());
    return Matches;
}
```

I'm wondering of my complexity here.

- I have a sorted array of String and I must search of matches with the given prefix,
- the first index is binary search so it is Log n
- the last index is also Log n
- matches [j] and terms[i] is m + m  where terms are the whole array of strings and matches is the matches strings with given prefix
- Array.sort is mLogm

so the complexity is `2Log n + 2m + mlogm` so its  `logn +m +mlog m` or how?

It should be in the assignment logn + mlogm in the worst case and I don't know how to fix it?